# BASH - Getting an rsh command to return a value or to timeout

Tags: linux, bash, variables, timeout, rsh

I am trying to set a variable in a Bash script to the results of running a command on a remote machine via rsh with a timeout option, such as...

```
timeout -s KILL 2 rsh jane df -h | grep StorageMedia
                  2.7T  2.1T  607G  78% /mnt/StorageMedia
```

I have tried the following...

```
rshresult="$(timeout -s KILL 3 rsh remotemachine df -h | grep StorageMedia)"

and

rshresult=`timeout -s KILL 3 rsh remotemachine df -h | grep StorageMedia`
```

...but both timeout after 3 seconds without setting $rshresult.

Running

Comment: What are you expecting `rshresult` to be when the command is killed due to timeout?

Comment: Both examples return the words 'Killed' rather than the expected results

Comment: Does the command always finish within 3 seconds otherwise, so that a 30 second timeout makes no difference except taking longer? Does `timeout -s KILL 2 rsh remotemachine df -h | grep StorageMedia | cat` finish successfully, without you interrupting it in any way? Are there any other messages?

Comment: It usually finishes within a few seconds, but I've had a few occasions where it never completes at all